# Excel VBA Selenium - element is not clickable

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a module that looks up prices on a website. The website brings up a table of matching parts to the one searched for so VBA is meant to go to the first option, click on it to expand the details and saves the price and part number.

It was working totally fine but is now showing the following error when clicking on the first option:

```
Selenium Error element click intercepted: Element <a class=”js-product-list-showDetails” style=”” data-producturl = “/p/details/25001979”
Href”/mini-com174 tx6a8482-10gig8482-tg-style-jack-module-orange/p/2500/1979”>…</a> is not clickable at point (702,36) other element would receive click: <div class = “gbgraybar-utility-menu_component”>
```

I looked up the error and I tried to use `.actions.movetoelement`. However I see from the browser that it is not clicking the element. Please view the snippet below

```
Private ch As Selenium.ChromeDriver

    Dim firstMatch As Selenium.WebElement
    
    Set firstMatch = ch.FindElementByClass("js-product-list-showDetails")
    ch.Actions.MoveToElement(firstMatch).Click
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me. I figured out the reason was a warning message that the website started to exhibit after login. The window was being shown in front of the element on which I was trying to click. I checked the box "don't show this message anymore", and it solved the problem.

Other possible explanations: https://www.testim.io/blog/selenium-element-is-not-clickable-at-point/